# Wireless Network API for Windows Mobile 5.0

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, mobile, wireless

I would like to programmatically get a list of available wireless networks (by SSID) using a Windows Mobile 5/6 device.  Does anyone know how to do this or where I might find information on accessing the WIFI adapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenNETCF [Smart Device Framework](http://smartdeviceframework.com) implements a fairly robust set of WZC APIs in the [OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/d79a4a4f-93be-3c85-477b-5298d1141978.htm) namespace.

Comment: I've done exactly the poster is trying to do with this code. It works very well.